# Connecting to SQL server database with PHP and Windows drivers

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, drivers

I was trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Database with PHP using the mssql set of functions that WERE in php. Since I am using php 5.5, these functions are deprecated I think, but I read that there is a solution, which is downloading the drivers windows is providing. I downloaded and installed them from the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Now the only thing is unclear to me is how to use them. Do these drivers re-activate the mssql (which I am sure it is not the case since I tried the code using mssql_connect and it threw a php error saying that the function could not be found)?

Can anybody give me an example of a MSSQL connection with these drivers?

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried this yet? [PHP: mssql-connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

Comment: nope... isnt it deprecated?